# SQL Server: How to make count(*) of Ages groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, group-by, count

I have a Table Users with users and a Age column with their ages.

| Name | Age |
| --- | --- |
| User1 | 19 |
| User2 | 25 |
| User3 | 75 |

I want to show their ages and count it.
But I don't want to make the count for each age specifically. I want to do it in groups of ages like this:

| Age group | Count |
| --- | --- |
| <18 | 5 |
| 19-34 | 2 |
| >75 | 2 |

How can I do this?

Comment: You can use a CASE to obtain a number per each age range that you need and then group by such number.

Comment: Hint: `CASE WHEN AGE < 18 THEN ... WHEN Age < 35 THEN ... ELSE ... END`

Comment: Side note: storing age in a database is silly, you would have to update it every year

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Categorize the records using case statements.
2. Group them and count

---

```
    Select a.AgeGroup, count(*) Count from (
select 
Case when  Age < 19 then '<19' 
     when Age between 19 and 34 then '19-34'
     when  Age > 75 then '>75' end AgeGroup 
from age ) a
group by a.AgeGroup
```

Comment: I tried your option, but It causes an error in the group by statment. It says that 'AgeGroup' is not valid

Comment: it didnt work ?

Comment: can you try again ? i updated

Comment: Ok. Now let's make it more difficult. Lets say that User table do not have an 'age' column but a bith date like: (01/03/1995). If instead of using the column age I put a Function that gives me the age based on column birth date (like: Case when  dbo.FuncGiveAge(Birth_Date)< 19 then '<19' .... from User) a group by a.AgeGroup. It will work? Thanks.

Comment: yep. it will work. if dbo.FuncGiveAge is good , it will %100

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please note your desired output for that question can't be obtained from the source data you've provided us with.

Second gap is between "19-34" and "> 75" that's why I've added "else" in the output

Another thing to mention is to gap in your logic between "<18" and "19-34" - in this way you'll loose those who are 18 years old. It has to be either "<= 18" or ( "< 18" and "18-34").

The condition "> 75" will ignore those who are 75 years old too.

But here is the answer based on your question and the source data

```
select case when age < 18 then '< 18' when age between 19 and 34 then '19-34' when age > 75 then '> 75' else 'else' end age_group,
       count(1)
  from test_data
 group by case when age < 18 then '< 18' when age between 19 and 34 then '19-34' when age > 75 then '> 75' else 'else' end
```